# PowerShell: Find similar filenames in a directory

Tags: powershell

In a purely hypothetical situation of a person that downloaded some TV episodes, but is wondering if he/she accidentally downloaded an HDTV, a WEBRip and a WEB-DL version of an episode, how could PowerShell find these 'duplicates' so the lower quality versions can be automagically  deleted?

First, I'd get all the files in the directory:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Exclude '*.nfo','*.srt','*.idx','*.sub' |
  Sort-Object -Property Name
```

I exclude the non-video extensions for now, since they would cause false positives. I would still have to deal with them though (during the delete phase).

At this point, I would likely use a ForEach construct to parse through the files one by one and look for files that have the same episode number. If there are any, they should be looked at.

Assuming a common spaces equals dots notation here, a typical filename would be `AwesomeSeries.S01E01.HDTV.x264-RLSGRP`

To compare, I need to get only the episode number. In the above case, that means `S01E01`:

```
If ($File.BaseName -match 'S*(\d{1,2})(x|E)(\d{1,2})') { $EpisodeNumber = $Matches[0] }
```

*In the case of `S01E01E02` I would simply add a second if-statement, so I'm not concerned with that for now.*

`$EpisodeNumber` should now contain `S01E01`. I can use that to discover if there are any other files with that episode number in `$Files`. I can do that with:

```
$Files -match $EpisodeNumber
```

This is where my trouble starts. The above will also return the file I'm processing. I could at this point handle the duplicates immediately, but then I would have to do the `Get-ChildItem` again because otherwise the same match would be returned when the ForEach construct gets to the duplicate file which would then result in an error.

I could store the files I wish to delete in an array and process them after the ForEach contruct is over, but then I'd still have to filter out all the duplicates. After all, in the ForEach loop,
`AwesomeSeries.S01E01.HDTV.x264-RLSGRP`
would first match
`AwesomeSeries.S01E01.WEB-DL.x264.x264-RLSGRP`, only for
`AwesomeSeries.S01E01.WEB-DL.x264.x264-RLSGRP`
to match
`AwesomeSeries.S01E01.HDTV.x264-RLSGRP` afterwards.

So maybe I should process every episode number only once, but how?

I get the feeling I'm being very inefficient here and there must be a better way to do this, so I'm asking for help. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I've answered what I _think_ the issue is but am not sure without the full code. I would suggest storing all the files in an array as you run through and deleting at the end. You can exclude the current file as this will always be found, and use `Select-Object -Unique` at the end on the "Files to delete" array... does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Filter the `$Files` array to exclude the current file when matching:

```
($Files | Where-Object {$_.FullName -ne $File.FullName}) -match $EpisodeNumber
```

Regarding the duplicates in the array the end, you can use `Select-Object -Unique` to only get distinct entries.

Comment: Your answer does present a solution to the issues in my thinking process (including my tunnel-vision, normally, I'd be the first to point out we could use a where-clause). But I still have to parse all files for every file to find matches, which is inefficient. I did forget about the Unique switch though, thanks for the reminder, you just helped fixed another script I was having issues with.
Matt's answer below also fixes the inefficiency by using the grouping, something I hadn't considered yet. So I'm going to build on that.
Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Consider [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) and - as you'll be using Matt's answer - [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how to get the episode number let's use that to group the files together.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Exclude '*.nfo','*.srt','*.idx','*.sub' | Select-Object FullName, @{Name="EpisodeIndex";Expression={
    # We do not have to do it like this but if your detection logic gets more complicated then having
    # this select-object block will be a cleaner option then using a calculated property
    If ($_.BaseName -match 'S*(\d{1,2})(x|E)(\d{1,2})'){$Matches[0]}
}}

# Group the files by season episode index (that have one). Return groups that have more than one member as those would need attention.
$Files | Where-Object{$_.EpisodeIndex } | Group-Object -Property EpisodeIndex | 
    Where-Object{$_.Count -gt 1} | ForEach-Object{
    # Expand the group members
    $_.Group
    # Not sure how you plan on dealing with it. 
}
```

Comment: Something I always forget is to use `-Path $Directory.FullName` or the listing will be empty (a filesystem-object is not a path, but its property is). Other than that, I hadn't considered this approach. I'll play with it and see if I can get the full script working. Thanks!